# What is this Ubuntu theme?

Tags: themes

I was wondering if one of you knew what theme this is? I really want it and I was wondering if this could help me out.

Here's the youtube video, I'm curious of what theme he has: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3CBrCVAXTM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Looking at the parts of the video, the person is using a slightly older version of Ubuntu with GNOME 3 desktop. The Window theme appears to be the default Ambiance theme - the window buttons you see on the Chromium windows is a thing Chrome can do to its own windows:

  [image]
  [image]
  The theme for the editor as well is probably individual to that program.

  Ambiance should be available by default on Ubuntu (if not installed, you can install the [`light-themes` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/light-themes) with `sudo apt-get install light-themes`). If you want to use it with GNOME Shell 3.12+ or the newer GTK apps that come with it, [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/install-ambiance-and-radiance-themes.html) may help
- The Desktop looks like the GNOME 3 Shell, probably before 3.10 (when they merged the menus). It has the default annoying dark theme.
- The icon theme looks like the default [Humanity](https://launchpad.net/humanity) theme or similar.
- There many similar wallpapers available (e.g. [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M7eq.jpg), a low quality version of the one from the video can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Xga.png).

Comment: Good answer!  I am going to delete mine.  It also looks like you found the closer match to the wallpaper being used there (joys of being colorblind here:) ).  Well done!  +1